# How do I stop this array from only printing/remembering the latest thing put into the array?

Tags: java, arrays

I don't know if the array itself is broken or if the code to print the array is broken

```
/*This is the main class that prints out everything */.

//Start the problems loop 
        for (int i = 0; i < session.getNumProb(); i++) {
            //Set random values for factors
            cards.setFactors();
            
            //Create problems
            cards.setProb(session); 
            
            //Determine correct/incorrect answer, update running score
            cards.setResponse(session);
            
            //Add the problem to the history array
            session.setHistory(cards);
        }
        //Set score percentage 
        session.setScorePct();
        
        //Print out summary
        session.prtSummary();
        
        //Print out history array and outro
        session.prtHistoryAndOutro();
        

______________________________________________________________________________
/* This sets the history based on questions asked */

//setHistory
    public void setHistory(Cards c) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numProb; i++) {
            history[i] = c.getA() + oper + c.getB() + " = " + c.getResponse() + ", " + c.getCorInc() + ", correct answer is " + c.getC();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
____________________________________________________________________________
/* This prints out the history array */

//prtHistoryAndOutro
    public void prtHistoryAndOutro() {
        System.out.println("Problems");
        for (int i = 0; i < numProb; i++) {
            System.out.println(history[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        
        System.out.println("Thank you for using the 3312 FlashCard System, " + name + ".");
        System.out.println("Come back and play again real soon!");
    }
```

I don't know where something is going wrong but it should be within these three pieces of code. Also the bottom two pieces are within the same class

Comment: Random snippets of code are unlikely to yield a complete answer. But I note that `setHistory` is called `session.getNumProb()` times and in turn runs `numProb` times. That seems like a bug. I would assume `setHistory` should take an `i` parameter and only manipulate the `history` for `i`. But that is an assumption. Good luck!

Comment: more complete code needed

Comment: Can you explain what the value `numProb` represents. It seems like you are overriting your existing history with this line: `history[i]` until the index `numProb`. Don't you want to add this element to the beginning/end of your history?